# multiple measurements for classification; which one to choose?

Tags: classification, repeated-measures, similarities, multi-class, multilabel

There are five different classes (labels) where the new points have to be classified at. For each new point, five different measurements are conducted, resulting into similar although different values for each variable. That is, each new point is presented in five different “versions” with the same ID and slight variations of the independent variables.
The problem I am trying to solve is to select the “best version” of each point to assign it to the “most suitable” class. This actually means that only one version of each new point should be classified in only one of the available classes (labels). 
Are there any algorithms and/or methodologies that can determine which is the optimal version of the point and in which class should be classified?

Comment: Is there a reason that there are five classes and five versions of data points? Or, is it just that there are five different measurements of the same sample and we are trying to find the most expressive one and use it for classification with, say, m classes?

Comment: @gunes the number of classes and measurements is just an example. yes you can actually sat that there are five different measurements of the same sample and I am trying to find out the most expressive one to use it for classification. However, one of the measurements - say n1 - can be more "similar" with one of the classes - say m1 - while another measurement can be more similar with another or even the same class. The point is to "compare" all measurements with all classes and find out the optimal one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I don’t see a conceptual difference than typical classification. Because, your measurements for the same data sample are just your features, even if they’re different measurements of the same element. Your features might have high correlation but this doesn’t change the nature of the problem,  only the choice of the learning algorithm.

Comment: I do not see how this works as a typical classification. For each measurement the features are the same and their **values** may be similar but **not identical**. This means that depending on the choice of measurement (i.e. measurement1, measurement2, etc, of the same features), the same data point can be classified into a different class. But which one is the best measurement? which one results into the optimal classification? whichever algorithm I choose it does not solve the problem of which of the measurements to use, unless there is an algorithm I am not aware of.

Comment: I've changed the wording slightly. I didn't mean identical values. I think that different measurements can be regarded as different features for your data samples. It doesn't matter if they all represent the same concept. The problem here is to predict the class given the measurements. One algorithm (doesn't matter what it is because we're trying to frame the nature of the problem) can decide the class by looking at these, for example by trying to choose the most representative measurement as you said, or making an ensemble decision, or do some other fancy stuff etc.

Comment: I believe I'm being misunderstood and this is my fault. I have changed the title question and edited the post. My intention is not to understand if my problem is a classification one. I am aware that a classification algorithm is needed. My problem is how to deal with multiple measurements.